# CSS transform origin not centered correctly

Tags: css

I have the following snippet of CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-o-keyframes spin {
0% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% { -o-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-ms-keyframes spin {
0% { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-keyframes spin {
0% { transform: rotate(0deg);}
100% { transform: rotate(360deg);}
} 

header .spinner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-animation:spin 1s ease-out .5s;
    -moz-animation:spin 1s ease-out .5s;
    animation:spin 1s ease-out .5s;
    transform-origin: 50%;
}
```

the animation runs fine, however the origin is slightly wrong making it look like the img is jumping when rotating.

Comment: Have you tried fixed width instead of %?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Justinas yes I have but I still have the problem